# How to Unlink a File from Website's Folder when MSSQL Table Row is Deleted Using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-delete, unlink

I am trying to make the link `<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?del=true&orderid={$row['orderid']}' style='color:black;' onclick='return show_confirm();'>Delete</a>`
delete the specific row from the MSSQL table using the while function. Currently, the bottom code works fine and deletes the specific row from the table, but I would now like it to unlink a file from the `sharedstorage` folder. The file that gets unlinked has it's filename stored in the `name` column for that table row. Each table row has a `name` column that contains a unique file's name from the file that is located in the `sharedstorage` folder.

My problem in simple terms is when a table row gets deleted, the file for that row in my website's `sharedstorage` folder remains and does not get deleted with the row.

Here is the code for when the delete link is hit for that specific row:

```
// delete from table
    if ($_GET['del'] == 'true') {
       // cast id as int for security
       $id = (int) $_GET['orderid'];
       // delete row from table
       $sql = "DELETE FROM shareddrive WHERE orderid = '$id'";
       $result = mssql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());
       // select the info, ordering by usort
       $sql = "SELECT orderid, name, type FROM shareddrive ORDER BY orderid";
       $result = mssql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());
       // initialize a counter for rewriting usort
       $job_pos_sortt = 1;
       // while there is info to be fetched...
       while ($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $job_poss = $r['orderid'];
          // update the usort number to the one in the next number
          $sql = "update shareddrive SET orderid = '$job_pos_sortt' WHERE name = '$job_poss'";
          $update = mssql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());
          // inc to next avail number
          $job_pos_sortt++;
       } // end while // end if del
    }
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mention unlink, but it isn't in the code?

Comment: I am trying to add an unlink function to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// delete from table
    if ($_GET['del'] == 'true') {
       // cast id as int for security
       $id = (int) $_GET['orderid'];
       // delete row from table

       $file = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("select name from shareddrive where orderid = $id"));
       unlink($file[0]);     

       $sql = "DELETE FROM shareddrive WHERE orderid = '$id'";
       $result = mssql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());
       // select the info, ordering by usort
       $sql = "SELECT orderid, name, type FROM shareddrive ORDER BY orderid";
       $result = mssql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());
       // initialize a counter for rewriting usort
       $job_pos_sortt = 1;
       // while there is info to be fetched...
       while ($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $job_poss = $r['orderid'];
          // update the usort number to the one in the next number
          $sql = "update shareddrive SET orderid = '$job_pos_sortt' WHERE name = '$job_poss'";
          $update = mssql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mssql_get_last_message());
          // inc to next avail number
          $job_pos_sortt++;
       } // end while // end if del
    }
```

Comment: I am using MSSQL, so mysql_fetch_array would have to be something else. I am going to try `mssql_fetch_assoc` and I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work. It says `Warning: unlink() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\Hostindstaffportal\sharedstorage.php on line 1202`.

Comment: You shouldn't ask for these. Plus here you didn't even try by yourself. Can't upvote, sorry.